# clip-path: Combine circle and polygon

Tags: css, clip-path

Is it possible to combine the clip-path shapes? I haven't found anything to suggest that it is possible.. If it's not possible, do you have another solution to solve this?

I use clip-path polygon to create a line going downwards in a table, and I need some of the line to have circles as well. This is the shape I want:

[image]

I have played around and tried stuff like this:

```
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 40% 100%, 60% 100%, 60% 0), circle(8px at 50% 50%);
```

and

```
      clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 40% 100%, 60% 100%, 60% 0);
      clip-path: circle(8px at 50% 50%);
```

but with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you investigated clip-path: path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mask can do it:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-mask:
    /* the circle*/
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#000 98%,#0000),
    /* the line             width=60% */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 50%/60% 100% no-repeat;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```